# Add 3 decimal places to everywhere except minicart, cart and checkout Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, minicart

I have come across issue where I want to show 3 decimal places everywhere on the site except cart, checkout and minicart. For that I have added this code to my functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals' , 'custom_price_decimals', 20, 1 );
function custom_price_decimals( $decimals ) {
    if( is_checkout() || is_page( 'cart' ) || is_cart() ) {
        $decimals = 2;
    } else{
        $decimals = 3;
    }
    return $decimals;
}
```

It shows the results on cart and checkout with 2 decimal places and the rest of the site 3 decimal places. The issue here is that because mini-cart.php isn't on separate page it will show prices with 3 decimals places instead of 2. Can anyone suggest me a workaround because I am not seeing one. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a look into [`cart/mini-cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3a76aa42555f037a0a565e9f0feaa43f89b197d2/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php) of the WC templates, you will find [this line](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3a76aa42555f037a0a565e9f0feaa43f89b197d2/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php#L37):

```php
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

So, if you want to make sure you only have 2 decimals inside the minicart, where this filter is applied, you can add a custom filter and apply your logic to only keep 2 decimals, for example using the wc price formatting function [`wc_price`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-formatting-functions.html#source-view.561):

```php
add_filter(
    hook_name: 'woocommerce_cart_item_price',
    accepted_args: 3,
    callback: function (string $price, array $item, string $key): string {
        return wc_price(
            price: $item['data']->get_price(),
            args: [ 'decimals' => 2 ],
        );
    },
);
```

- Note, I did not test the snippet.
- Also note that named function arguments require at least PHP 8

---

Lower than PHP 8:

```php
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_cart_item_price',
    function (string $price, array $item, string $key): string {
        return wc_price(
            $item['data']->get_price(),
            [ 'decimals' => 2 ],
        );
    },
    10,
    3,
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and this seems like a good solution but unfortunately this site is not using PHP 8

Comment: @in2d in this case you can just strip the named arguments, make sure to match the required order, `accepted_args` for example has to be on fourth place, etc (added it to the answer)

Comment: This line return an error [ 'decimals': 2 ],

Comment: Ah yea, my fault, we are not in JS, we are in PHP, therefore it has to be `=>` instead of `:`