# WooCommerce Mini-cart.php round prices to 2 decimal places

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, minicart

I have an issue with WooCommerce mini-cart.php and showing how many decimal places I want to show. On the rest of the site I want to show 3 decimal places but in mini-cart I would like to show 2 decimal places. Is there a way I can modifiy mini-cart.php template so the prices get rounded down to 2 decimal places?

Cheers

Comment: You already asked about that in [Add 3 decimal places to everywhere except minicart, cart and checkout Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248585/add-3-decimal-places-to-everywhere-except-minicart-cart-and-checkout-woocommerc), so this should really ot need a new question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num = "25";
echo number_format((float)$num, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 25.00
```

Thanks You Can Try This.